# Temperature of the System right after mixing water at different temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

Let's assume that 100gm of water at temperature 25$^{\circ}$C and another of 300gm at 90$^{\circ}$C. After mixing both samples, we would eventually get a constant temperature (say $T^{\circ}_f$) and we can do all sorts of heat calculation.

But I was wondering what would be the temperature of the whole system, right after we mix both the samples. Since, it would take some time to reach $T^{\circ}_f$, if we try to measure the overall instantaneous temperature of the system, what would we measure?

Thanks.

Comment: You said _the temperatrue of the whole system_, but this physical quantity isn't defined right after the mix. In fact, temperature is a mesoscopic physical quantity, which implies that it's just defined at a small scale: in your case, since the system isn't homogeneous before a "long" time, it's temperature doesn't even _exists_.

Comment: @Spirine But isn't the temperature defined as the average Kinetic Energy of the particles in the system? How can we imagine where temperature doesn't exists?

Comment: Then if you want your inhomogeneous system to have a temperature, define it as the average of all the local temperature of this system. But this has no real physical interpretation: what is the temperature of a cold bucket of water and a hot bucket of water ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the 'whole system' is the total of 400g of water, the temperature of the 'whole system' immediately after mixing is what you call the constant temperature Tfo. It is not 'instantaneously' any other value before the water is thoroughly mixed, and does not cool down to Tfo from some other value.  The 'whole system' of water does not necessarily take a 'long time' to reach Tfo, it 'instantaneously' reaches Tfo.

Tfo is obtained by doing 'a sort of heat calculation.'  Usually this calculation requires knowledge of the specific heat capacities of the components being mixed or brought into thermal contact.  However, since the same substance (water) is being mixed here, the temperature after mixing is the weighted average of the initial temperatures, with the weighting done by mass - ie 
Tfo=(100*25+300*90)/(100+300).